# Properly defining a static NSString* c-style array under ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In my implementation file, I have a static 2-dimensional c-style array of NSString* defined as:

```
static NSString* TheColorArray[][3] = {
    [RedType] = {@"red", @"blah", @"YES"},
    [BlueType] = {@"blue", @"yadda", @"YES"},
    .....
}
```

The method in question accesses the array like:

```
-(NSString*)value:(NSInteger)value {
    return TheColorArray[value][0];
}
```

This all seems to work fine about 99% of the time...but when it fails to work it always fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x11`

I've verified that my `value` parameter is not beyond the bounds of the array.  It seems odd that the address is `0x11`...which kind of implies that the array has not been initialized.

So what is happening here?  Is there some "gotcha" I need to be aware of with ARC and c-style arrays?

Comment: Why not just an NSArray and be done w/it?

Comment: I'm about to make it an NSArray, but I would like to understand what is wrong with my code...

Comment: @TReddy I ran this thing in a tight loop calling the function 100,000 times, and I couldn't get a crash.

Comment: Can you show your declarations for RedType, BlueType, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Crashlytics did not report the crash correctly.  The address, according to the "real" crash report on the iPad, was not 0x11, but something that looked more like a legitimate address.  After further testing, I discovered that there was an edge-case situation where `value` was not in the range of my array, which resulted in the crash.

In light of everything, I'm still going to move to an `NSArray*` of `NSString*` objects because I don't yet understand if ARC works nicely with c-style arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is clear that *structs* cannot contain ARC'd objects, we could argue that this applies to multidimensional array datums as well, though it doesn't say so.  Did you try this:

`static NSString __unsafe_unretained * TheColorArray[][3] = ...`

This will take the objects allocated here out of ARC and remove any possibility that the compiler is aggressively nulling where it shouldn't be.

Assuming that's the problem.  Maybe if you're able to step back with the debugger, can you see what symbol is being dereferenced when it errs?